# How to only show dollar signs in the top row of SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have two cells that belong to both a row group and a column group. Cell A is literally just a dollar sign and cell B contains the actual number. This iterates both vertically and horizontally. I need the dollar sign to repeat across columns for just the top row but not exist (or be written in white) for all subsequent rows.

I've tried every iteration of the HideDuplicates setting. The closest I came is showing a dollar sign in only the top left cell, meaning it doesn't iterate vertically but also doesn't repeat horizontally as desired. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Share your report design and expected results, it's difficult to understand your problem from the question as it stands. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask